# Google app engine for websites which updates every second?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need advice if it is worthwhile to explore Google APP Engine option, so if learned and experienced user could comment, it would really help (I do not need code)

Present Scenario:
I have a website, where the data need to be updated every second ? it is built on .NET, and a user need to have updated data every time they visit, the data changes every second. The users have bookmarked the URLs so the data is changed and URL remains the same.

We also have a lot static data, which users access for researching and reading.

Experience with cloud:
We had tried using the Website with one of the Big Players (not with the original cloud company, with their nearest competitor ;) we had problems the file getting stuck at times (essentially some users are seeing update, some not), and they had 'Modified Trust' rights level implemented, which was restricting us at multiple places (Auto Generating files in directory)

My Questions:
(a) You think in above scenario, Google App Engine could help ?
(b) URL re-writing more specifically generating 200 server return instead of 404 would that be possible or the 404 being trapped and coverted into 302 and redirected ? 
(c) We had a hole in the pocket on hosting fees when we moved from traditional to cloud and now we are back on traditional server with Load Balancer, do you think on heavy traffic site do we stick with traditional or look at google app to lower our costs ?

I look forward in hearing comments..

Thanking everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*(a) You think in above scenario, Google App Engine could help ?*

The problem with users not seeing data is a factor of caching or eventual consistency in your database. That's not going to be "solved" by moving to a new cloud provider. The appengine datastore uses eventual consistency, but you can solve that problem by using memcache to store data that changes frequently. That said, Appengine doesn't give you complete control over memcache so you may still have problems solving that issue.

*(b) URL re-writing more specifically generating 200 server return instead of 404 would that be possible or the 404 being trapped and coverted into 302 and redirected ?*

Not really sure what you mean here. You can certainly return 302 or 200 responses instead of 404s using any web framework worth its salt

(c) When designed well, appengine can be very cost effective, but when not optimized it can be a money sink... there are a lot of good papers out there about how to effectively optimize it, but if you are talking about a lot of users hitting the site every second you are going to pay for it.

Comment: I know, I don't need .Net I could move to other languages, provided we could the functionality as mentioned above :)

Comment: Thanks Rick, as of now we are not using Mem,we generate HTML and leave (like generating multiple HTML per second on Multiple server), so that there is no load on the DB, and when a user refreshes the data, it would automatically picks up the html from the server which is relatively free (handled by load server), now if use the same scenario do you think it might work ?

Comment: On appengine? Well, appengine has no file system so you would have to cache those generated HTML pages in memcache. MC is shared across servers, so you *should* get the correct versions, but you might run into a problem with the edge caching of static files... I would instead use rest calls to pull in the dynamic content via javascript on the client end and use static html templates to display it.